How to add custom branch types in Bitbucket Branching Model?
I’m using Bitbucket and working with the Branching Model feature to manage our repository branches. Currently, I can see predefined branch types like feature/, bugfix/, hotfix/, and release/, and I can rename or configure them.
However, I’d like to add a new branch type, specifically chore/, to the branching model to organize non-feature tasks such as refactoring or updating dependencies.
I don’t see an option to add new branch types in the Repository Settings > Branching Model screen—only the ability to rename or modify existing branch types.
My Questions:
Is it possible to add custom branch types (e.g., chore/) to the branching model in Bitbucket?
If so, how can I do this? If not, are there any workarounds or alternative ways to manage this kind of branching structure in Bitbucket?
I’ve checked the Repository Settings > Branching Model section, but I don’t see an option to add new branch types—only to modify existing ones.
I’m aware I can manually create branches with a chore/ prefix, but I’d like it to be integrated into the branching model to ensure consistency across the team.
Any help or insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

is this bb cloud or bb server?

For BB Server
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver0819/branches-1416825883.html#Branches-model
By default, branch settings set at the project level are inherited by the repositories. Repository admins can either choose to inherit the project-level settings or override it by configuring custom settings at the repository level.
Later when you modify project settings, only settings in repositories that are set to inherit the project-level setting change to match the project branch settings.
Starting from Bitbucket 8.10, project admins can also restrict changes to repository-level settings. Note that when you restrict changes, any custom settings saved at the repository-level are deleted and the repositories inherit project settings.

Good to know:

New repositories will have the branching model enabled by default, and use
the default branch prefixes.
Enabled branch types can't have empty prefixes, have a 30 character limit, and can't overlap (for example PROD and PRODUCT would overlap).


Configure a project's branching model
To configure a branching model for a project (requires project admin permission):

Go to Project settings > Branches.
Choose the details of branching
model for repositories that inherit the project settings, then
select Save.
Optional: To restrict repository-level changes,
select Don't allow changes to branch settings from the Restrict changes to repository settings menu.

Configure a repository's branching model
To configure the branching model for a repository (requires repository admin permission):

Go to Repository settings > Branches.
Under Project settings inheritance, select Use custom settings.
Choose the details of your repository branching model, then select Save.


thanks a lot for your prompt reply, to answer your question it's BB cloud .
In BB cloud i tried both :
Project settings > Branching model
Repository settings > Branching model
only 3 settings are available ( under both project and repo ) :

setting the Development branch
setting the Production branch
Branch prefixes
"Define the default prefixes for new branches, to allow automated workflows and make branch types clearer." (exactly how it's mentioned) here i can see a list of prefixed branch names but i CANT add a new type (prefixes).


I think they only allow the default ones, but you can change the prefix of those pre-defined branches
